# Design: why does JavaScript have separate Function and Object objects, and why do these have their own separate prototype objects?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I've come across the [following diagram](http://www.mollypages.org/misc/js.mp) which looks rather messy.

So here comes my question:

Why does JavaScipt have separate Function and Object function objects
(instead of for instance simply having everything defined at the top level
by the user point to a single prototype object Root, and with the prototype
of Root pointing back to Root, which would seem to be a much simpler
and more intuitive design)?

Thanks.

---

Sorry for my misunderstanding. Now I realize:

- JavaScript has primitive data types and objects. The primitive data types are
  boolean, number, string, null, and undefined. When needed the first three of
  these are treated as instances of Boolean, Number, and String. Everything
  else is an object, including functions, arrays, regular expressions, and
  dates. Functions may be used as constructors or as ordinary functions.
  When a function is used as a constructor it can be used to instantiate
  object instances via the new operator. The prototype of the instantiated
  instance (accessed via the `__proto__` property) is set to the constructor's
  'prototype' property when the instance is instantiated. The `__proto__`
  members are used to resolve properties via the prototypical inheritance chain.

  Since functions are more specialized than objects there is a Function.prototype
  object stuck in the prototypical inheritance chain between functions and the
  top-level Object.prototype object. The Function and Object constructor
  functions should themselves not normally be needed since we can make
  use of the function keyword and object literals directly.

Comment: Because Function instances are different from Object instances. They're functions.

Comment: Because Objects shouldn't be executable by nature.

Comment: But my understanding is that in JavaScript everything is an object and a function at the same time. See this post: http://markdalgleish.com/2012/10/a-touch-of-class-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: Well, that diagram is simply *drawn* messy.

Comment: @JohnSonderson your understanding is incorrect, I'm afraid. Not everything in JavaScript is an object, and certainly not everything is a function.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: No. Every function is an object, but not everything is an object, and not every object is a function.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: Your understanding is wrong. While everything is an object, and functions are object, not everything is a function.

Comment: That's like saying that everything on the highway is a vehicle and a motorcycle at the same time.

Comment: non-object constructors are specializers that provide more functionality to certain objects. this makes them handier than plain objects, and prevents every object from needlessly having Array or Function methods.

Comment: Thanks, but how can something which is not an object have a constructor? Can you please provide an example of a non-object constructor?

Comment: This links discusses whether everything in JavaScript is an object or not: http://www.quora.com/Is-everything-an-object-in-Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor function can only have one prototype (at any given time).  When an object is constructed, it becomes related to the prototype object referenced by its constructor. Function objects (and String objects and Date objects, etc) have prototypes with different sets of properties.  All objects have prototype chains that eventually go back to the Object prototype.

The case with Function instances is even more distinct: the constructed objects are functions.  The Function constructor (which is part of the native runtime) gives the constructed object internal properties that make it possible for the runtime to access the block of code associated with functions. Specifically (this is all from [section 13.2 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2):

- The `[[Call]]` internal property is set to the value of the parsed function body (the code of the function)
- The `[[Construct]]` internal property is *also* set to the function body (and that's why all functions can be used as constructors)
- The `[[HasInstance]]` internal property is made to refer to the internal code that implements [section 15.3.5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.3), which makes `instanceOf` work

and similarly for internal properties `[[Code]]`, `[[FormalParameters]]`, `[[Scope]]`, and others. In other words, a function object is *iternally* special in a lot of ways. In its relationship to the Function prototype, however, it's not really special. The function prototype is consulted during the process of property lookup on the function object itself. For example, when resolving an expression like this:

```
var bound = function() { alert(this); }.bind("hello");
```

the runtime has to locate the property "bind". It won't be found on the function object itself, but it *will* be found on the prototype.

Comment: What do you mean by constructor function? Isn't really every function at the same time also a constructor in JavaScript? Aren't functions and objects the same thing in JavaScript. So, if they are the same, then why have both Function and Object? Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: @JohnSonderson yes that's true - any function can be a constructor. My point was that an object has only one constructor, and the value of that function object's "prototype" property is what determines the prototype chain for the new object.

Comment: @JohnSonderson (well, there's also `Object.create()`, but it's still the case that an object only gets one shot at being related to a prototype object).

Comment: Thanks, I've reworded my question.

Comment: Careful!! While it's true to say "*all **native** ECMAScript functions created by the Function constructor are constructors*", it doesn't apply to all **javascript** functions or even all ECMAScript functions. Many built–in methods are functions and are not constructors (e.g. Array.prototype.slice), and nearly all host methods are functions but not constructors (e.g. document.getElementById()).

Comment: True. It seems I've also missed this point. Some built-in functions cannot be invoked as constructors.

Comment: @RobG yes sorry, of course that's true.

Comment: @JohnSonderson I'm going to re-word the edit, because your changes altered the sense of what I was getting at. I wasn't talking about properties (visible properties) on the Function prototype. I was talking about internal (not visible) properties that are used to make Function instances work as functions.  That process does not involve the Function prototype.